# SWIG - No default typemap for std::list when wrapping to C#, how can I do?

Tags: c#, c++, swig, typemaps

I am currently working on wrapping a big C++ library to C# using SWIG. I am facing a big problem, since my library use a big amount of *std::list*, and it seems that SWIG (I am using the last release 3.0.12) doesn't supply a default mapping for *std::list*. I looked all over the web, nothing found.. I am quite surprised because *std::list* are quite similar to C# LinkedList !

Anyway, I am not in SWIG for a long time, so I don't really know how to do.. All I know is that I absolutely can't change all the *std::list* in my lib, and I'd really like to wrap them in C# LinkedList, but I don't know if it's possible and if I can do it easily..

I looked over typemaps, but I'm not sure it would worked correctly because mapping *std::list* to a LinkedList seems more complicated than using simple typemaps..

People, I need you to advise me ! 
Thanks in advance,
Quentin.

Comment: Have you considered  C++ / CLI?

Comment: Actually, we already tried this solution. But in the end, it did'nt correpsond to what we wanted, for many reasons. The main reason is we want to touch to the lib source as less as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for those who are facing the same issue like I was, I finally decided to make my own implementation of std::list to C# LinkedList.

I made a pull request on the SWIG GitHub today. If someone is interested, go check it. It is not perfect but work for now.

Comment: Here is the link to the pull request: https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/989